# What to set Redirect URI for OAuth2 in Salesforce?

Tags: python, oauth, salesforce

I'm using the following library for Salesforce OAuth Request: https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-oauth-request

I've created a Connected App, but have no idea what to set the redirect uri. Can I just set it to "https://www.google.com/"?

I just want to connect to Salesforce's Chatter API via python code, and don't care where the user gets directed as long as I get a refresh token from the oauth2 protocol

Comment: I suggest you contact the owner of the project.

Comment: Well, that would be me, and this is a project I've never done before.